# Google maps API v3: Can not call method 'lat' of null

Tags: google-maps-api-3, android-webview

I am using Google maps API v3, and this is my HTML file (mylocation.html) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mylocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {zoom: 6};

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions)n);

            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function  (position) {
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                        position.coords.longitude);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        map: map,
                        position: pos,
                        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
                    });

                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function () {
                    handleNoGeolocation(true);
                });
            } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleNoGeolocation(false);
            }
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag) {
                var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
            } else {
                var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
            }
            var options = {
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
                content: content
            };
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
            map.setCenter(options.position);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it on the Google Chrome, it works fine, and shows me my location.

In my project, I using `WebVew` to show this HTML file on Android. But when I run it, in `LogCat`, I get the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of null at file:///mnt/sdcard/myloction.html:12"

(I have saved `mylocation.html` in the SDCard).

I'm not sure how to fix this? Could someone guide me with this?

Comment: This is most probably typo just here `mapOptions)n);` ?

Comment: With FireFox I got just blank screen after refusing to share my location. Chrome shows your location with error message `Error: The Geolocation service failed.` which is ok.

Answer (score 2):

To access Geolocation in the WebView, you need to do a bit of setup first.

You first must enable the feature in WebSettings: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setGeolocationEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setGeolocationEnabled%28boolean%29)

And you must also implement the WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(java.lang.String, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback%29)

And please also ensure that your application has the appropriate Android permissions to access location.